# Control alignment input-group-btn

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put on same line firstname,lastname inputs and button.
The total width of the above 3, should be equal to the 'xxxxxxx' input.

you can find the code here

http://jsfiddle.net/zxb53wjq/1/

```
<div class="container">  


  <form role="form" action="" method="post">   
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="form-group">

            <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="xxxxxxxx"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Application:</label>                         
               <div class="input-group">                              
                 <input style="width:50% " class="form-control " placeholder="first name"  name="firstname" type="text" />
                 <input style="width:50% " class="form-control " placeholder="last name"  name="lastname" type="text" />
               </div>
               <span class="input-group-btn">                       
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addApplicationBtn" name="addApplicationBtn">Add</button>
                       </span>
             </div>                                                                                                                                             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

using bootstrap css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is not the same as bootstrap 3. Most of the classes have been renamed and unlike bootstrap 3, bootstrap 4 uses `flex` box.

## Bootstrap 4

- Remove the two inputs' inline styles
- Use `input-group-append` instead of `input-group-btn`.

  ```
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <input  class="form-control " placeholder="last name"  name="lastname" type="text" />

        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addApplicationBtn" name="addApplicationBtn">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/fhg3qx96/

## Bootstrap 3

- Use `input-group-btn` inside `input-group`

  ```
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" style="width:50%" placeholder="first name" name="firstname" type="text" />
        <input class="form-control" style="width:50%" placeholder="last name" name="lastname" type="text" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addApplicationBtn" name="addApplicationBtn">Add</button>
        </span>
      </div>
  ```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQrJeW

Comment: there is a problem, once I add bootstrap.css.

Comment: @Yev are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: I am Using 3.3.7

Comment: this is perfect.